# How to generate a random number within a range only once?

Tags: excel, random, numbers

I want to randomize numbers in a range between `x` and `y`. The problem is, while the random numbers are generated, Excel generates the numbers again, each time I make a change in the spreadsheet.

The purpose of this question is for the sake of generating realistic-looking ID Numbers, basically, for showing a group of students how to generate a range of ID numbers in Excel for a Mail Merge, later on. However, I don't want them to panic, so, I want to make the Generated Numbers be generated only once. For instance, let's say that `=RANDBETWEEN(20,45)` generates `31` for one cell, I want that particular cell to retain that value. In addition, I also want to demonstrate to students who want to go one step further, how to insert a string prior to the Numbers. For example, "Case: " (without quotes), followed by the generated value. Some students even asked how to add multiple generated numbers, separated by dashes.

The code I use: `=RANDBETWEEN(20,45)`.

As mentioned, I only want the numbers to be generated once. Instead, every time I modify the spreadsheet, the values change.

Comment: Sounds like you want to replace your random call with a hash.  I don't know anything about Excel, though, so I can't offer useful code.

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE:

I used the following formula: `="CASE: "&RANDBETWEEN(20,45)& "-" & RANDBETWEEN(20,45)` , and it produces `CASE: 21-38`. All I need is to make the value stay the same as I make changes to the Spreadsheet.

Comment: Please edit your question to clarify it, don't use an answer for that purpose.